# How to convert csv file to syslog in Java

Tags: java, spring, csv, apache-camel, syslog

I need to convert csv file to syslog.

CSV:(From)

```
"Type","RowID","Name"
"SecurityIncident","ace5c4550c76","MalwareInfection"
"SecurityIncident","ace5c4550c77","MalwareInfection"
```

Syslog: To

```
<13>1 2023-09-09T10:19:28.428851-08:00 DESKTOP-TVVB676 - - - [LOG@14506 EventReceivedTime="2020-09-09 10:19:28" SourceModuleName="csv" SourceModuleType="file" Type="SecurityIncident" RowID="ace5c4550c76" Name="MalwareInfection"
<13>1 2023-09-09T10:19:28.428851-08:00 DESKTOP-TVVB676 - - - [LOG@14506 EventReceivedTime="2020-09-09 10:19:28" SourceModuleName="csv" SourceModuleType="file" Type="SecurityIncident" RowID="ace5c4550c77" Name="MalwareInfection"
```

How to do it in Java? Is there any java library available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java code for converting CSV to Syslog

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "file.csv"; // Replace with your CSV file path
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader());

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                String type = csvRecord.get("Type");
                String rowID = csvRecord.get("RowID");
                String name = csvRecord.get("Name");
                
                String timestamp = LocalDateTime.now().toString();
                String hostname = "DESKTOP-TVVB676";
                
                String syslogEntry = String.format("<13>1 %s %s - - - [LOG@14506 EventReceivedTime=\"%s\" " +
                        "SourceModuleName=\"csv\" SourceModuleType=\"file\" Type=\"%s\" RowID=\"%s\" Name=\"%s\"",
                        timestamp, hostname, timestamp, type, rowID, name);
                
                System.out.println(syslogEntry);
            }

            csvParser.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<13>1 2023-09-14T19:11:52.057131900 DESKTOP-TVVB676 - - - [LOG@14506 EventReceivedTime="2023-09-14T19:11:52.057131900" SourceModuleName="csv" SourceModuleType="file" Type="SecurityIncident" RowID="ace5c4550c76" Name="MalwareInfection"
<13>1 2023-09-14T19:11:52.068649300 DESKTOP-TVVB676 - - - [LOG@14506 EventReceivedTime="2023-09-14T19:11:52.068649300" SourceModuleName="csv" SourceModuleType="file" Type="SecurityIncident" RowID="ace5c4550c77" Name="MalwareInfection"
```

Comment: It worked and helped for my need